# Google compute: Why persistent ssd disks are slower than persistent standard disks?

Tags: performance, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, io

I ran several IO benchmarks and I cannot understand how pd-ssd offers a worse IO throughtput than pd-standard.

In my tests I boot a VM with a bootable disk pd-ssd of 30 or 250GB, and I still get worse performance than with a pd-standard disk of 100GB. I can share the results of my benchmarks. But I believe I am missing something...

Comment: What was your benchmark methodology?

Comment: @RobbieMckennie I used sysbench and diskbenchmark to validate the IO performance. I used the simple tests. Ofc both machines were identical, it only differs the boot disk type. All these comes because I also discovered a slow IO behavior while using etcd.

Comment: Very strange. No idea. Are you sure you haven't gotten ssd and standard mixed up? ;-)

Comment: You don’t know that you have one hard disk VM and one SSD VM. All you know is that you’re being charged the prices for one hard disk VM and one SSD VM. The one that you’re paying hard disk prices for might actually have SSD, if there was a shortage of hard disk resources when you created it and Google chose to fill the request with higher-spec hardware rather than deny it.

Comment: @MikeScott don't understand how this can happen if I decide to use a specific type of boot disk. Anyway I ran this tests couple of times so I assume there wasn't any shortage of hard disk resources.

Comment: Check this [documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#size_price_performance) on the comparison and information on PD-SSD and PD-Standard. SSD persistent disks can achieve greater IOPS and throughput performance on instances with greater numbers of vCPUs. Standard persistent disk IOPS and throughput performance increases linearly with the size of the disk until it reaches the following per-instance limits. Also, check out [this article](http://www.cmips.net/2015/01/25/benchmarking-google-cloud-compute-engine/) with info. on benchmarking GCE disk performance.

Answer (score 4):

PD-SSD is optimized for IO latency and IO throughput, whereas sysbench file layout needs sequential write bandwidth which PD-Standard can deliver better at small sizes.

Indeed, for 100GiB PD-Standard the sysbench prepare takes about half of the time of a 100GiB PD-SSD because PD-Standard is able to write at 120MiB/s whereas the PD-SSD is limited at 48MiB/s.

The benchmark itself though shows PD-SSD winning substantially in IO latency and IOPS:

```
100GiB PD-Standard:
    total number of events:              30928
    total time taken by event execution: 289.2202
    per-request statistics:
         min:                                  0.00ms
         avg:                                  9.35ms
         max:                                 94.20ms
         approx.  95 percentile:              27.00ms

100GiB PD-SSD:
    total number of events:              412308
    total time taken by event execution: 193.5045
    per-request statistics:
         min:                                  0.00ms
         avg:                                  0.47ms
         max:                                 16.67ms
         approx.  95 percentile:               0.95ms
```

My benchmark commands:

```
sysbench --test=fileio --file-total-size=50G prepare
sysbench --test=fileio --file-total-size=50G \
  --file-test-mode=rndrw --init-rng=on --max-time=300 --max-requests=0 run
```